# Prove that $f:K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if $G_f$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Question:

> Let $K$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f:K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if $G_f$ is compact in
>   $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I have the following definitions:

Defn 1.

> If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ the graph
>   of $f$ is the set $G_f = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in A, y =
>  f(x)\}$.

Defn 2.

> A sequence $((x_n, y_n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements in
>   $\mathbb{R}^2$ converges to $(x,y)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ if
>   $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ and $(y_n) \rightarrow y$ as $n \rightarrow
>  \infty$.

Defn 3.

> A subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is compact if every sequence in $E$ has
>   a subsequence that converges to a limit that is also in $E$.

**My Working**

I *think* my argument for the only if direction is correct. Would be good if someone can verify:

$\left(\Longrightarrow\right)$ Assume $f$ is continuous on $K$ where $K$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$. Note that,
\begin{align*}
G_f = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in K, y = f(x)\} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in K, y \in f(K)\}
\end{align*}
To show $G_f$ is compact, we need to show that any sequence $((x_n, y_n)) = ((x_n, f(x_n))$ in $G_f$ has a subsequence which converges to an element also in $G_f$. In other words, we must show that any sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$ has a subsequence which converges to an element in $K$ and any sequence $(f(x_n))$ in $f(K)$ has a subsequence which converges to an element in $f(K)$.

Since $K$ is compact, then it is true that any sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$ has a subsequence which converges to an element in $K$. Now since $f$ is continuous, and compactness is preserved by continuous functions, $f(K)$ is also compact. Thus, it is true that any sequence $(f(x_n))$ in $f(K)$ has a subsequence which converges to an element in $f(K)$. Therefore, $G_f$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Query**

Is my proof for the only if direction correct? How do I prove the if direction? I have a feeling that I need to use the properties of compactness, ie, bounded and closed, but not sure how to prove it exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused in how to use the definitions provided : Suppose $K$ is compact and $f$ is continuous - you want to show that $G_f$ is compact. So choose a sequence $(x_n, f(x_n)) \subset G_f$. So far so good - how do you choose a convergent subsequence?

Well, you work on the first component first : Since $(x_n) \subset K$, choose a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Now $x_{n_k} \to x_0$, then $f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x_0)$, so the subsequence
$$
(x_{n_k}, f(x_{n_k}))
$$
of the original sequence converges to $(x_0, f(x_0)) \in G_f$.

---

For the other direction, suppose $G_f$ is compact, choose a sequence $(x_n) \subset K$ such that $x_n \to x_0 \in K$. You want to show that $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$; so consider
$$
z_n: =(x_n, f(x_n)) \in G_f
$$
The trick here is: If every convergent subsequence of $(z_n)$ converges to the same point, then $z_n$ must converge to that point. (First prove this!)

So suppose $z_{n_k} \to z_0 = (x_1, f(x_1)) \in G_f$, then it follows that $x_{n_k} \to x_1$ and so $x_1 = x_0$, and hence $f(x_1) = f(x_0)$. Thus, the only limit of $(z_n)$ is $(x_0, f(x_0))$. And so $z_n \to (x_0, f(x_0))$.

Hence, $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Instead of "the trick": $f$ is continuous in $x_0$, therefore if $x_n\to x_0$, then $f(x_n)\to f(x_0)$. That's easy to prove using the definitions of limits. Then in turn, by Defn 2, $(x_n,f(x_n))\to(x_0,f(x_0))$.

Comment: @Heimdall: I don't understand - the trick is used to show that $f$ is continuous, so one can't assume that!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Still, it's simpler, you don't need that trick. Assuming $f$ is not continuous, we can construct subsequence so that $f(x_n)$ converges to either $\infty$ of a real number not equalling $f(x_0)$. The subsequence $(x_n,f(x_n))$ either escapes to infinity or converges to a point not in the graph. Still, I guess I've just proven the "trick"...